# Replaced fragment still received events

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, fragment

I am writing an android app using ActionBarSherlock

My layout file is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/fragment_menu"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/menu_size"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/dummy"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Depending the category is selected in Menu fragment, I replace the fragment in dummy FrameLayout.Eg:

```
 Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putInt(ProgramDetailFrament.EXTRA_PROGRAM_ID, programId);
    final ProgramDetailFrament fragment = ProgramDetailFrament.newInstance(extras);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.dummy, fragment)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
    getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

But the replaced fragment still receives touch/click event when I interact with the visible fragment. I don't know whether SherlockFragment is related to this issue?

I solved that by setting click event on the root layout of the visible fragment and do nothing in this event. But It seems a ugly solution.

Anyone knows how to solve it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you state in your question, you're trying to **replace** a Fragment with another, so you should use the [replace method of FragmentTransaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29).

Here's roughly how to do it :

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putInt(ProgramDetailFrament.EXTRA_PROGRAM_ID, programId);
ProgramDetailFrament fragment = ProgramDetailFrament.newInstance(extras);

FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.id_of_fragment_container, fragment, DETAIL_FRAGMENT_TAG);
ft.commit();
```

I hope this helps ;-)

Comment: I already used replace method of FragmentTransation. But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to use the **replace** function instead of **add**. What you're doing is adding a fragment on top of the other one, so you're creating a stack of fragments which are all still visible, only you don't see them because the top fragment covers all the other ones.

Use replace instead of add:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.dummy, fragment)
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .commit();
getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

This will remove all the other fragments in the dummy container and add the fragment you selected.

Comment: Why are you suggesting addToBackStack(null) ?

Comment: I just copied his example